# How to upgrade sqlite3 on Ubuntu 12.04 + Apache Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite, upgrade

I have an old Ubuntu server 12.04, with many software's configuration so I can't upgrade to new version Ubuntu. In theses, Apache with PHP 5.5.26 and SQlite3 3.7.9. How do I update / upgrade only my sqlite3 to new version 3.8.2 or upper?

I've tried remove + install php5-sqlite via apt-get but nothing change.

I've download and install the sqlite3 3.8.10 package from www.sqlite.org by

```
sudo wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-autoconf-3081002.tar.gz
tar -xzvf sqlite-autoconf-3081002.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3081002
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And my sqlite3 --version is updated, but my PHP's sqlite not change.

P/S : I need sqlite's function **instr** that is not in my old sqlite's version.

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your sqlite.so file in php extensions. Have a look here:

[PHP SQLite Extension Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php)

See, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks about that but I can't found an easy guide command-line for me and Ubuntu version. Pls help detail to me.

Comment: Have you used this command: sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite and when your connect to DB, do you use $db = new SQLite3('test.db'); ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/607945/unbuntu-14-04-nginx-php5-fpm-sqlite3-pdo-sqlite-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Sqlite3 is working on my system and it's version 3.7.9. I know this version from this example : http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php and use **print_r($db->version());**

Comment: Over search, I know my SQLite3 version 3.7.9 is default version when I install LAMP. And even SQLite3 command-line version is upgraded, as my way, PHP5's SQLite3 not upgrade. I can see that again in **phpinfo()**. So I think because PHP's SQLite3 library. I find how to update it ;)